# How do I combine data taken separately into a single dataset?

Tags: r

I have a dataset comprised of leaves which I've weighed individually in order of emergence (first emerged through final emergence), and I'd like to combine these masses so that I have the entire mass of all the leaves for each individual plant.

How would I add these up using R programming language, or what would I need to google to get started on figuring this out?

```
    structure(list(Tray = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Plant = c(2, 2, 2, 
2, 3, 3), Treatment = structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("2TLH", 
"E2TL", "EH", "WL"), class = "factor"), PreSwitch = c("Soil", 
"Soil", "Soil", "Soil", "Soil", "Soil"), PostSwitch = c("Soil", 
"Soil", "Soil", "Soil", "Soil", "Soil"), Pellet = c(1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1), Rep = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Date = structure(c(1618963200, 
1618963200, 1618963200, 1618963200, 1618963200, 1618963200), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), DAP = c(60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60), Position = c(2, 
1, 3, 4, 4, 3), Whorl = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "factor"), PetioleLength = c(1.229, 
1.365, 1.713, 1.02, 0, 1.408), BladeLength = c(1.604, 1.755, 
2.466, 2.672, 0.267, 2.662), BladeWidth = c(1.023, 1.185, 1.803, 
1.805, 0.077, 1.771), BladeArea = c(1.289, 1.634, 3.492, 3.789, 
0.016, 3.704), BladePerimeter = c(6.721, 7.812, 11.61, 12.958, 
1.019, 14.863), BladeCircularity = c(0.359, 0.336, 0.326, 0.284, 
0.196, 0.211), BPR = c(1.30512611879577, 1.28571428571429, 1.43957968476357, 
2.61960784313725, NA, 1.890625), Leaf.Mass = c(9, 11, 31, 33, 
32, 33), BladeAR = c(1.56793743890518, 1.48101265822785, 1.36772046589018, 
1.4803324099723, 3.46753246753247, 1.50310559006211), Subirrigation = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Genotype = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Location = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: please share a reproducible sample of your data set with `dput(head(data))`.

Comment: structure(list(Tray = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Plant = c(2, 2, 2, 
2, 3, 3), Treatment = structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("2TLH", 
"E2TL", "EH", "WL"), class = "factor"), PreSwitch = c("Soil", 
"Soil", "Soil", "Soil", "Soil", "Soil"), PostSwitch = c("Soil", 
"Soil", "Soil", "Soil", "Soil", "Soil"), Pellet = c(1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1), Rep = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
"POSIXt")), DAP = c(60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60), Position = c(2, 
1, 3, 4, 4, 3), Whorl = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "factor"),  Leaf.Mass = c(9, 11, 31, 33, 
32, 33),

Comment: Unfortunately, the dataset is massive and it wouldn't let me post the set in its entirety. I edited out the extraneous stuff, but some vital stuff (like location) had to be left out of the above.

Comment: Ok what would you like to calculate here? If you would like to calculate a parameter for a specific variable(s) per any grouping (like the answer below), just let us know.

Answer (score 0):

I may be missing something but isn't this a sum by Plant?

One solution below sums it for each plant into a separate table with just the totals and the second summarizes and adds it back to the main data set in a single step.

```
library(tidyverse)

#summary data set
plant_total <- df %>% group_by(Plant) %>% summarize(plant_weight = sum(Leaf.Mass, na.rm= TRUE))

#add plant_weight column to df data set
plant_total <- df %>% group_by(Plant) %>% mutate(plant_weight = sum(Leaf.Mass, na.rm = TRUE))
```